# How to pass Bold string and string like link in json?

Tags: c#, asp.net, json, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

i am passing json to fire base for web push notification. my Json string is following.

```
{"to":"<token>","notification":{"body":"jack: Sent message to abc\n Received message from xyz","title":"\ App Notification","icon":"http://www.icon.png","click_action":"https://www.example.com"}}
```

and i am geting following push notification.

[image]

But now i want the title in bold like **App Notification** and link like [Google](http://www.google.com). so how can i pass json for geting this Result.

Comment: where and how are those notifications being shown ?

Comment: Try sending the text surrounded with double asterisk like `**App Notification**` to make it bold and see if that works

Comment: @Cristian S i am passing JSON from api for generate push Notification and it is display on website, android and ios registered device.

Comment: The problem is that I do not exactly know how the rendering process works in your case. It might depend on the frontend technologies (framework) you use. You can easily save the html as string in the json and render it correctly. Double `*` sounds like markdown to me.

Comment: JSON has no formatting. You must handle that in the UI.

Comment: @Dumisani i tried **App Notification** but not works

Comment: "not works", "not working", that's not good enough. Do you get anything at all? What does it look like? What's wrong with it? You need to be more explicit than just "it's not working", we can't guess what you mean by that. Most likely the rendering engine for your notifications displays your notification as pure text, that's not something you can fix by changing the message itself, you need to fix the rendering engine.

Answer (score 0):

JSON only stores the data in a compact human-readable form. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSON

It doesnt format text at all, thats something you need to handle in the frontend side.

For instance you can store the title as a HTML String : `<b>App Notification</b>` or whatever... and let the UI render it correctly.

Comment: i have tried with <b>App Notification</b> and ** App Notification ** but its not working.

Comment: I think you didnt understand what I tried to explain you. Its not about how you save the text in the JSON its about how you render it ! Check this http://jsfiddle.net/a83oLxde/4/

Answer (score 0):

JSON is use for systems to communicate data just like the XML in the old days. That is why is mostly use for API strickly data.